# Multiple Wordpress loops, hide first loop on second page

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I've construced two Wordpress loops with numeric pagination as follows:

```
 <div class="container" style="background:#ccc">
            <?
                $paged2 = isset( $_GET['paged2'] ) ? (int) $_GET['paged2'] : 1;

                // Custom Loop with Pagination 1
                // http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Usage
                $args1 = array(
                    'paged'          => false,
                    'category_name' => 'latest',
                    'posts_per_page' => 1,
                );
                $query1 = new WP_Query( $args1 );

                while ( $query1->have_posts() ) : $query1->the_post();
                    the_title();
                    the_category(' ');
                    the_excerpt();
                endwhile;

            ?>
            <!-- second -->
            <?
                $args2 = array(
                    'paged'          => $paged2,
                    'category_name' => 'uncategorized',
                    'posts_per_page' => 2,
                );
                $query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );

                while ( $query2->have_posts() ) : $query2->the_post();
                    the_title();
                    the_category(' ');
                    the_excerpt();
                endwhile;

                $pag_args2 = array(
                    'format'  => '?paged2=%#%',
                    'current' => $paged2,
                    'total'   => $query2->max_num_pages,
                    'add_args' => array( 'paged1' => $paged1 )
                );
                echo paginate_links( $pag_args2 );
            ?>
    </div>
    <!-- container -->
```

Everything works fine, but the paginatin page also shows the 'latest' post loop, although I've set the pagination to false. 
How could I hide the first loop on the pagination pages?
Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use wp_reset_postdata() function after your loop end
follow this code, may be it'll help you

```
<?php
// example args
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 3 );

// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <!-- start of the loop -->
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?><!-- end of the loop -->

    <!-- put pagination functions here -->
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately the first loop is still visible on the pagination pages after adding this in.